# SAS PROC GENMOD - Why does consistent syntax produce different reference categories for two different binary variables?

Tags: syntax, sas, regression

I am running a series of bivariate log binomial regressions in PROC GENMOD, using the same outcome and one binary (1/0) predictor per model. I use the exact same syntax, swapping out only the predictor variable, and in one of the models, the regression is for predictor category 1 vs. predictor category 0, while in the other model, it does the opposite. What could be going on?

My predictor variables are:

Housing_Insecure_Dich_BL:
0 = No,
1 = Yes

PrEP_Effic_Risk_Red_binary_BL:
0 = Below 90%,
1 = 90%+

Model 1:

```
proc genmod data=full3 descending;
class Housing_Insecure_Dich_BL (ref=first);
model Almost_Always_Take_3m = Housing_Insecure_Dich_BL / dist=bin link=log waldci ;
estimate 'Housing_Insecure_Dich_BL' Housing_Insecure_Dich_BL 1 -1/exp;
run;
```

Results:
Class Level Information table lists the values as "Yes No" - meaning that it is comparing Yes vs. No, i.e., 1 vs 0.
The prevalence ratio makes sense given the raw percentages.

Model 2:

```
proc genmod data=full3 descending;
class PrEP_Effic_Risk_Red_binary_BL (ref=first);
model Almost_Always_Take_3m = PrEP_Effic_Risk_Red_binary_BL / dist=bin link=log waldci ;
estimate 'PrEP_Effic_Risk_Red_binary_BL' PrEP_Effic_Risk_Red_binary_BL 1 -1/exp;
run;
```

Results:
Class Level Information table lists the values as "Below 90% 90%+" - meaning that it is comparing ZERO to ONE - why is it doing this, when I've specified ref=first, and the exact same syntax with a different 1-0 coded variable produces the expected reference category coding?
The prevalence ratio matches what is expected for Zero vs One, but that is not what I want.

I can just change the syntax for Model 2 to say ref=last, or ref="Below 90%", but I would rather understand what is going on and be able to use uniform syntax since all my predictors are coded the same.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have formats on your predictor variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you're probably doing.

```
proc format;
  value smokef
  0 = 'Nonsmoker'
  1 = 'Smoker'
  ;
  value bpf
  0 = 'Normal BP'
  1 = 'Higher BP'
  ;
  value statusf
  0 = 'Dead'
  1 = 'Alive'
  ;
quit;

data heart;
  set sashelp.heart;
  smokeflag = (smoking ne 0);
  bpflag    = (bp_status ne 'Normal');
  statusflag= (status = 'Alive');
  format 
    smokeflag  smokef.
    bpflag     bpf.
    statusflag statusf.
  ;
run;

proc genmod data=heart;
class smokeflag;
model statusflag = smokeflag;
estimate 'Smokeflag' smokeflag 1 -1/exp;
run;


proc genmod data=heart;
class bpflag;
model statusflag = bpflag;
estimate 'Blood Pressure flag' bpflag 1 -1/exp;
run;
```

Notice the same issue - it compares 'Nonsmoker Smoker' (0 1) but 'Higher BP Normal BP' (1 0).  That's because GENMOD's default `order` is `order=formatted`.  `N` comes before `S`, but `H` comes before `N`...

The desired results could either be obtained by changing the format to include the number (so `1 Smoker 0 Nonsmoker` etc.) or by using the `order=internal` option:

```
proc genmod data=heart;
class smokeflag (ref=first order=internal);
model statusflag = smokeflag;
estimate 'Smokeflag' smokeflag 1 -1/exp;
run;


proc genmod data=heart;
class bpflag (ref=first order=internal);
model statusflag = bpflag;
estimate 'Blood Pressure flag' bpflag 1 -1/exp;
run;
```

`order=internal` tells SAS to use the unformatted order.

Some procedures also support formats saved with `notsorted`, but in my testing that's not available on GLM (usually is available when `preloadfmt` is available).

Comment: Thank you so much! "order=internal" fixed the issue completely! I figured it might have something to do with the format label but was not aware of what you described. I appreciate it!